# How to modify HashMaps according to values

Tags: java

Let's say I have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` containing usernames and their position as an int in a queue or line. How would I go about removing a user from the queue and subsequently update all the values for the users behind?

Comment: what do you mean by " update all the values for the users behind"?

Comment: @Rias, let's say I remove a user that is in the middle, how should I go about updating all of the users who were behind the user that was removed

Explanation:
User1, 1
User4, 2
User8, 3
// I remove User4
// How do I update the hashMap to look like this:
User1, 1
User8, 2

Comment: You can make use of `Concurrent HashMap` in order to update the same map.concurrent hash map allows concurrent read and write operation to the map.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Why not use ArrayList/LinkedList? 
It's ordered and you can get position using indexOf(), if you are. incrementing just by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    static Map<String, Integer> queueMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        queueMap.put("Arvind", 5);
        queueMap.put("Avinash", 6);
        queueMap.put("Kumar", 7);
        queueMap.put("Lightcaster", 8);
        queueMap.put("Stackoverflow", 9);
        System.out.println("Before: " + queueMap);
        removeFromQueue("Kumar");
        System.out.println("After: " + queueMap);
    }

    static void removeFromQueue(String user) {
        final Integer userPlace = queueMap.get(user);
        if (userPlace != null) {
            queueMap.replaceAll((k, v) -> v > userPlace ? v - 1 : v);
            queueMap.remove(user);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before: {Arvind=5, Avinash=6, Kumar=7, Lightcaster=8, Stackoverflow=9}
After: {Arvind=5, Avinash=6, Lightcaster=7, Stackoverflow=8}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found a method of doing this that I believe should work. @Rias, thanks for the direction to concurrent hashMaps which provided a way to complete the same task I was facing.

```
public void removeFromQueue(String user) {
    if (queueMap.containsKey(user)) {
        int userPlace = queueMap.get(user);
        for (String currentser : queueMap.keySet()) {
            if (queueMap.get(currentUser) > userPlace) {
                queueMap.put(user, queueMap.get(currentUser) - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The self-answer can be improved. Most obviously you are doing two map look ups for each entry when none are required (as we are iterating). Also there is now the handy `Map.replaceAll` method. So perhaps:

```
public void removeFromQueue(String user) {
    Integer userPlace = queueMap.get(user);
    if (userPlace != null) {
        queueMap.replaceAll((k, v) -> v>userPlace ? v-1 : v);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would that affect the users who were ahead of the user removed, remember I'm only trying to update the ones behind the user being removed.

Comment: @Lightcaster5 Yup. I made a mistake transliterating your code. Fixed. **Edit:** Hang on, is it? **Edit2:** No I was right the first time. Confusing someone behind in the queue has the higher number.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I didn't miss anything, why you can't use a simple `ArrayList<String>` for all the user names?

The list will keep the users in order by their index, which is the equivalent of the value in your map. Moreover, if you remove a user which his index is `i`, then all the users with index > `i` will be reorganized as you want (after the removal the new index of the user with index `i + 1` will be `i`)